# Issue with receiving responses from server and sending contact form

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, nodemailer

I'm working on a React app which has a server-side that sends a contact form to the client using Nodemailer and verifies the reCaptcha token.

The issues I'm having involve:

1. The console indicating that the URL cannot be found:

> http://localhost:1337/status -> Failed to load resource: the server
> responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
>
> http://localhost:1337/contact -> GET http://localhost:1337/contact 404
> (Not Found)

2. The form will not send even if the verification and form are complete, and will alert `Please Verify You Are Not A Robot` asthe button is clicked. I believe this is because of the valid state not being updated.
3. Previously, I used emailjs and switched to nodemailer to avoid the limitations of emailjs. Before the issue of the form sending, I noticed that the email was returning a `null` in the emailed form.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const axios = require('axios');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const port =  1337;

require('dotenv').config()
console.log(process.env)

app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(cors());
app.use("/", router);
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Server is running");
});

const contactEmail = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: "**.com",
    pass: `${process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_PASS}`,
  },
});

contactEmail.verify((error) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log("Ready to Send");
  }
});

router.post("/status", async (req, res) => {

  const firstname = req.body.firstname;
  const lastname = req.body.lastname;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const message = req.body.message; 

  const mail = {
    from: "**.com",
    to: "**.com",
    subject: "**",
    html: `
           <p>Name: ${firstname} ${lastname}</p>
           <p>Email: ${email}</p>
           <br/>
           <p>Message: ${message}</p>`,
  };
  contactEmail.sendMail(mail, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ status: "ERROR" });
    } else {
      res.json({ status: "Message Sent" });
    }
  });
})

router.post("/contact", async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.body;
  const secret = `${process.env.REACT_APP_SECRET_KEY}`;
  const captchaResponse = await axios.post(
    `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify`,
    {
      secret: secret,
      response: token,
    }
  );
  if (captchaResponse.status === 200) {
    res.status(200);
  } else {
    res.status(403);
  }
});
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server is listening on ${port}`);
});
```

**Contact.jsx**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect, useRef, Suspense, lazy} from 'react'
import Stockpic15 from '../../media/stockpic15.webp';
import ReCAPTCHA from "react-google-recaptcha";
import axios from 'axios';
import PageLoader from '../../Components/PageLoader';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

const Contact = () => {
  
  const [valid, setValid] = useState(false);
  const [status, setStatus] = useState("SEND");
  const form = useRef();
  const firstnameRef = useRef();
  const lastnameRef = useRef();
  const emailRef = useRef();
  const messageRef = useRef();

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(form.current);
    let details = {
      firstname: formData.get('firstname'),
      lastname: formData.get('lastname'),
      email: formData.get('email'),
      message: formData.get('message'),
    };
    const formValid = form.current.checkValidity();

    if (valid && formValid) {
    setStatus("SENDING...");
    try {
        let response = await fetch("http://localhost:1337/status", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify(details),
        });
        let result = await response.json();
        alert(result.status);
        setStatus("SENT");
        form.current.reset();
        return;
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        setStatus("FAILED");
      }
    } 
    else {
      alert("Please Verify You Are Not A Robot")
    }
  };

const captchaRef = useRef(null);

const reCaptchaValue = async () => {
  const token = captchaRef.current.getValue();
  console.log(token);
  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:1337/contact", {
      response: token,
    })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
      setValid(res.data.status);
      if (res.data.status === true) {
        alert('Verification Successful!');
      } else {
        alert("Please Verify You Are Not A Robot");
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
};

const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect (() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setLoading(false)
    }, 2000);
  }, [])

  const { register } = useForm();


const LazyNav = lazy(() => import('../../Components/Navigation.jsx'))
const LazyFooter = lazy(() => import('../../Components/Footer.jsx'))

  return (
    <>
    { loading ? <PageLoader loading={loading}/> :
  <div className=''>
    <Suspense fallback={<div />}>  
      <LazyNav/>
      </Suspense>
        <div>
          <div>
            Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum necessitatibus sunt, officia eveniet distinctio consequatur eius minima perspiciatis vel laborum assumenda magnam esse quae quas. Sint asperiores inventore eveniet iste!
          </div>
          <div>
            <img src={Stockpic15} alt="" />
          </div>
            <form ref={form} onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <input ref={firstnameRef} className='contact-input' type='text' name='firstname' placeholder='Your First Name' required {...register("firstname", { required: true})} />
              <input ref={lastnameRef} className='contact-input' type='text' name='lastname' placeholder='Your Last Name' required {...register("lastname", { required: true})} />
              <input ref={emailRef} className='contact-input' type='email' name='email' placeholder='Your Email Address' required 
              {...register("email", 
                {
                  required: true, 
                  pattern: {value: /^\S+@\S+$/i,}})} />
              <textarea ref={messageRef} name="message" rows="4" placeholder='Message' maxLength="6000" required htmlFor="message"></textarea>
              <ReCAPTCHA 
              sitekey={`${process.env.REACT_APP_SITE_KEY}`}
              ref={captchaRef}
              onChange={() =>
              reCaptchaValue()}
              className='flex justify-center sm:scale-75 tablet:scale-100'
              />
              <button type="submit" href="#_">
                <span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span></span>
                  <span>{status}</span>
                </span>
                <span"></span>
              </button>
          </form>
        </div>
        <Suspense>
      <LazyFooter/>
    </Suspense>
  </div>
    }
    </>
  )}

  export default Contact
```

In an attempt to resolve these issues, I have restarted the server and terminal; checked the server port was correct and added `"proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3000"` to the `package.json` on the server-side:

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "dev": "nodemon server.js",
    "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3000"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^9.17.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.21"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved by correcting the captchaResponse to send the value of success depending on whether the verification was successful or not and changing `response: token` to `token: token` on the client-side.

```
const reCaptchaValue = async () => {
  const token = captchaRef.current.getValue();
  console.log(token);
  await axios
    .post("http://localhost:1337/contact", {
      token: token,
    })
```

```
    if (captchaResponse.status === 200) {
      res.status(200).send({ success: true });
    } else {
      res.status(403).send({ success: false });
    }
```